# XML - Convert Value to Specific Format

Tags: c#

I'm loading a XML file into a GRIDVIEW and I managed to do so. But I'm currently stuck in one thing and that is, when I try to load one specific value (47.138). This value is supposed to be loaded in the following format (Minutes:Seconds.Mileseconds). Which in this case would be "0:47.138" .

My question is, how do I load this type of data and show it in the correct format?

```
XmlNodeList drivers = doc.GetElementsByTagName("Driver");

        foreach (XmlNode driver in drivers)
        {
            dInfo = new BusObjects.DriverInfo();

if (driver.ChildNodes[i].Name.Equals("BestLapTime"))
                    dInfo.FastestLap = Convert.ToDouble(driver.ChildNodes[i].InnerText).ToString("????");                     
            }
```

This is my DriverInfo.cs

```
    private double _fastestlap;

    public double FastestLap
    {
        get { return _fastestlap; }
        set { _fastestlap = value; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `TimeSpan` object and use that to format the text.

```
TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(47.138);
Console.WriteLine(ts.ToString(@"mm\:ss\.fff"));
```

In your `DriverInfo` class, you could have a method to do this for you.

```
public string GetFormattedTime()
{
   TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(_fastestlap);
   return ts.ToString(@"mm\:ss\.fff");

   //shorter version if you prefer
   //return TimeSpan.FromSeconds(_fastestlap).ToString(@"mm\:ss\.fff");
}
```

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287.aspx) has more information about custom TimeSpan formats.

Comment: Many thanks for the fast reply. Just a quick question though, should I keep the data type to "Double" on my DriverInfo class? And what should I put on my first block of code?

    if (driver.ChildNodes[i].Name.Equals("BestLapTime"))
                    dInfo.FastestLap = Convert.ToDouble(driver.ChildNodes[i].InnerText).ToString("????");

Comment: It's up to you on how you want to the persist the data, but if the source is in the format you've described, you can keep it as a `double`. You don't need the `ToString("????")` part because `FastestLap` is a double not a string .

Comment: So you mean like this?

`code`public double FastestLap
        {
            get { return _fastestlap; }
            set { _fastestlap = value; }
        }

        public string GetFormattedTime()
        {
            TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(_fastestlap);
            return ts.ToString(@"mm\:ss\.fff");

            //shorter version if you prefer
            //return TimeSpan.FromSeconds(_fastestlap).ToString(@"mm\:ss\.fff");
        }

Comment: `code`if (driver.ChildNodes[i].Name.Equals("BestLapTime"))
                        dInfo.FastestLap = Convert.ToDouble(driver.ChildNodes[i].InnerText);

EDIT:
In the GRID now show (47138) and not 0:47.138

Comment: Yes, I think so (code is a bit hard to read in the comments section). Try it and see.

Comment: In the GRID it shows (47138) and not 0:47.138  :( Thanks for the help anyway mate...

Comment: Oh sorry I missed that. Make sure that the grid is retrieving the data via the `GetFormattedTime` and not directly calling the `FastestLap` property.

Comment: if (driver.ChildNodes[i].Name.Equals("BestLapTime"))
dInfo.GetFormattedTime();

Like this? I get 0 in each row of my grid instead of the formatted time. I'm still learning and this is all new to me, therefore so many questions.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on [keyboardP's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13778959)....

```
foreach (XmlNode driver in drivers)
{
  dInfo = new BusObjects.DriverInfo();

  if (driver.ChildNodes[i].Name.Equals("BestLapTime"))
  {
    dInfo.FastestLap = Convert.ToDouble(driver.ChildNodes[i].InnerText);
  }
}

// you can use an auto property for FastestLap
public double FastestLap {get; set;}

// Add another property for FormattedFastestLap:
public string FormattedFastestLap 
{
    get { return TimeSpan.FromSeconds(FastestLap).ToString(@"mm\:ss\.fff"); }
}
```

In the `foreach` loop, you are setting the value of the FastestLap, which is a double. By creating another property called FormattedFastestLap, you can access the FastestLap property and convert the double into a string by first converting into a TimeSpan object and then returning the TimeSpan in a formatted string.

In your grid, you then bind the display to the FormattedFastestLap instead of the FastestLap property.

Comment: Hmmm, I did exactly what you wrote above. When I load the grid, It displays "02:18.000". I've tried changing the TimeSpan.FromSeconds to TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds and I get "07:51.738" . What I should be getting is "0:47.173". The XMLNode value is: "47.1738". Any idea of what I should do?

Comment: Not sure; if the value of FastestLap is indeed 47.1738, then the FormattedFastestLap will be 0:47.17. When you use both values side by side in the grid, what are the 2 values?

Comment: Solved. I had to do a small change on this line: dInfo.FastestLap = Convert.ToDouble(driver.ChildNodes[i].InnerText.Replace(".", ","));  Thanks alot for all the help.